# Summernote on Rails Production broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, summernote

I'm having some trouble with getting [Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails) to work correctly on my production Rails environment (on Heroku). I'm using `rails 4.2.0`, `bootstrap 4.1.3`, and `summernote-rails 0.8.10.0`.
Everything works fine locally but is broken on production.

[image: On local]

[image: On production]

There are no errors when the editor loads but as soon as you click in to any of the text fields there are the following errors:

First-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined
at e.hide (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:141)
at e.update (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:141)
at e.invoke (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:142)
at e.update (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:140)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.summernote.mousedown (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:140)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:33)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.m.handle (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:32)
at Object.trigger (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:33)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:33)
at Function.each (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:22)
```

Second-

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function
at i (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:139)
at e.current (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:139)
at e.currentStyle (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:140)
at e.invoke (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:142)
at e.updateCurrentStyle (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:141)
at e.invoke (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:142)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:141)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:33)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.m.handle (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:32)
at Object.trigger (application-817b47c5cec07e4f230739dba0885233c6c215d78b973ccec6560fa46ec08080.js:33)
```

Both these js errors seem to be coming from Bootstrap.

Also, I guess it does "work" on production but it the extra input fields and just looks broken. Like so-

[image]

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Changed the environment on Heroku to development and everything works. So Bootstrap is getting borked during minification. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Rails 5 and that fixed the minification problem.